# Group By Clause, Do i have to call all rows what i using in Select?

Tags: sql

Do I need to put all the column names in group by which I have select put in select?
for example in this simple query :

```
Select
    CustomerID,
    CompanyName,
    ContactName,
    ContactTitle,
    City,
    Country
From
    Customers
Group By
    Country,
    CompanyName,
    ContactName,
    ContactTitle,
    City,
    Country,
    CustomerID
```

I have to allways call same amount Group By what i used in Select?

Comment: It depends on what data you're after. Your query doesn't use any aggregate functions (like `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc) so there is no point to using `GROUP BY`. Remember that `GROUP BY` is *not* for sorting or partitioning rows (often people think that `GROUP BY` does partitioning, it does not). Generally if you have too many columns in your `GROUP BY` clause you're doing something wrong.

Comment: ahh that make sens for me, but for next egzample if i gonna use function like a Count in query. Do i have to call all of rest partition from select (like customerID, FirstName, LastName etc) or do i can choise like just 2 of them ?

Comment: On a side note: The company name should not be in the customers table, but in a company table. Same for city names and a city table. That (along with proper foreign key constraints) would prevent from typos ('Seattle' in one record, 'Seatle' in another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just selecting columns and you want the returned records to discard the exact duplicate rows? Then there are 2 methods.

1) group by
2) distinct

Your query doesn't use any of the aggregate functions like f.e. COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM, ...
So your query could use DISTINCT instead of a GROUP BY.

```
select DISTINCT
 CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, City, Country
from Customers
```

But if CustomerID is a primary key, then CustomerID would already make the result unique.
So then this query doesn't need a `GROUP BY` or a `DISTINCT` to only get unique records.

```
select CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, City, Country
from Customers
```

Note that one could have both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query.  But that's just pointless.  A `GROUP BY` already enforces the    uniqueness, so adding a `DISTINCT` to make them unique would just make the query slower for no reason.

As for the why all the columns in that select also have to be listed in the GROUP BY?   Some databases, f.e. MySql can be more tolerant about not having to group on all columns.  But it's a rule from one of the SQL Standards. So most databases enforce that.  It's to avoid potential misleading results.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY x, y` means you want one result row per x and y. So if you have a table with bills, you could group by year and month for instance and thus get the number of bills (`count(*)`) and the total (`sum(amount)`) per month.

So the question is what rows do you want to see. A row per company (with the number of their customers) maybe? A row per city? The `GROUP BY` clause contains exactly those columns mentioned.

Your `GROUP BY` clause does exactly nothing, as select customers and you group by customer ID (which should be the customer table's primary key).